# Php $ Html Navigation Issue

Tags: php, html

Well, Following is the function which select current page name. ex: index.php, owner.php, contactus.php etc. I created this function because i need to active a css id(#active) selector which highlight the current page.

**Function**

```
function curPageName() {
return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}
$pagename = curPageName();
```

**And this is my Navigation Code:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" <?php if($pagename == "index.php") echo "id='active'"; 
?>>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="owner.php" <?php if($pagename == "owner.php") echo "id='active'"; ?>>LIST 
YOUR PROPERTY</a></li>                        
<?php
$menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where status = 1");

while($re = mysql_fetch_array($menu))
{
$pageid = $re['pageid'];
$pagelink = $re['pagelink'];
$pagename = strtoupper($re['pagename']);
$pagedes =  $re['pagedes'];                     

echo "<li><a href='page.php?pageid=$pageid'>$pagename</a></li>";
}
?>                      

<li><a href="contactus.php" <?php if($pagename == "contactus.php") echo "id='active'"; 
?>>CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, My questions is It's active the css id selector to Index.php and owner.php. **BUT** It's doesn't active the css selector to contactus.php page.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: echo out $pagename and tell us what it says.

Comment: @Wayne Whitty I tested it It's show the current page ex:contactus.php.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing your code like that. Rendering PHP and HTML together is a recipe for disaster. Also, do not use mysql_query. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: But when i put it before the php code it's worked fine why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overwritten `$pagename` into `while loop`

```
while($re = mysql_fetch_array($menu))
{
$pageid = $re['pageid'];
$pagelink = $re['pagelink'];
$pagename = strtoupper($re['pagename']);

^^^^^ overwritten variable value change this variable name

$pagedes =  $re['pagedes'];                     

echo "<li><a href='page.php?pageid=$pageid'>$pagename</a></li>";
}

-------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv- this will be last value of while loop
<li><a href="contactus.php" <?php if($pagename == "contactus.php") echo "id='active'"; 
?>>CONTACT US</a></li>
```

Comment: OH!! GBD thanx I didn't see this. Can i ask you 1 more questions. How do i select current page name if it's something like. page.php?id=2 etc